# Making an HTTP request in WP7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I need to know how to make GET/POST requests to different servers from my WP7.1 (mango) App

I tried the usual System.Web and System.Web.HTTP and they're not supported by WP7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class

Answer (score 3):

`System.Web` is used to make web **servers** with ASP.Net.

You're looking for System.**Net** and its [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), which is supported by WP7..